# Problem with GDI generated fonts in 64-bit Vista

Tags: c#, gdi+, 64-bit, picturebox

We’re building a custom output display dialog.  In it we display thumbnails (bitmaps) in a listbox. There is also a larger, detail view which is a GDI vector image retrieved from PrintPreviewEventArgs (PreviewPrintController) and displayed in a WindowsFormsHost:PictureBox.   The thumbnail bitmaps are created from the original GDI image, so it would appear that the image did contain the text at some point.

All is fine on a 32-bit box. When we run the app on a 64-bit machine (we build targeting an x86 platform so we're running in the 32-bit emulator), the thumbnails are fine, but the main image is missing all text.  The graphic elements - lines, table borders and background colors, etc are rendered, but no text.

Any ideas? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem had to do with using TextRenderer.DrawText instead of Graphics.DrawString during the print.